# VBA, Adding trailing zeros

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make small VBA script, that would keep the leading zeros, and also would make the strings 8 characters long, and incase it's not it would add 0 to end of the number chain. It would also be nice, if the script would be able to go to next line automatically. Can some 1 help?

[image]

[Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bz2VT.png)

Comment: No need for VBA if you'd transform these values into actual numbers and use custom number formatting.

Comment: Please explain in what context you need to do this, and why you need to use VBA. What is the purpose of these number strings? How are you going to use these number strings afterwards?

Comment: Change the numbers from text to numbers (_Convert To Number_ when you click on the exclamation mark next to the selected cells).  Select and right-click the cells, select `Format Cells`, select `Custom` and enter `00000000` in the `Type:` box.  The cell will contain the number 2, but display 00000002.

Answer (score 0):

You can right-pad with zeros like this:

```vb
Dim c as range
For each c in selection.cells
    c.value = Left(c.value & String(8, "0"), 8)
Next c
```